# Setting custom MKPinAnnotationView images

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm trying to create three custom pin image annotations for an MKPinAnnotationView based on some criteria. In this case, I'm iterating through a for loop of bike station objects, checking if the number of available bikes is 0 and, if so, set one pin.image, and, if not, set another pin.image. I'm also checking if the number of docks is 0 and setting another image accordingly. I know that, in some cases, the first if statement evaluates to YES, but all the pin annotations are coming up with the image denoted in the else portion of the statement. I guess I'm confused as to where to instantiate the  MKAnnotationView and return it so that all my pin images are not returning the same image, as they are right now.

```
       - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
       for (DivvyStation *divvyStation in self.divvyStations) {
        if (divvyStation.availableBikes.intValue < 1) {
                MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
                pin.canShowCallout = YES;
                pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nobikes"];
                return pin; }
        else if (divvyStation.availableDocks.intValue < 1) {
                MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
                pin.canShowCallout = YES;
                pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dock"];
                return pin;}
        else {
            MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
            pin.canShowCallout = YES;
            pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Divvy-FB"];
            return pin;
              }
            }
   return nil;
}
```

Okay, I think I understand the problem, but my pins are displaying the default red color, so I don't think I'm having the custom class correctly adopt the MKAnnotation protocol. My custom class .h file is below. I read that the MKAnnotation protocol must implement a coordinate property, which I've added. Is there something I'm missing?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface DivvyStation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property NSNumber *identifier;
@property NSString *stationName;
@property NSNumber *availableDocks;
@property NSNumber *totalDocks;
@property NSNumber *latitude;
@property NSNumber *longitude;
@property NSString *statusValue;
@property NSNumber *statusKey;
@property NSNumber *availableBikes;
@property NSString *streetAddress1;
@property NSString *streetAddress2;
@property NSString *city;
@property NSString *postalCode;
@property NSString *location;
@property NSString *landMark;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to iterate through all of the bike stations in this method - it is called to obtain the pin view for a specific annotation. You need to check the number of bikes for the station that corresponds to the annotation that has been passed to this method. The way your code is currently written it will return the view that applies to the first station in your array for all annotations.

One thing you will notice is that MKAnnotation is a protocol, not an object that you need to subclass. This means that you can have an existing object in your data model adopt the MKAnnotation protocol.

In this case you could make your DivvyStation class adopt the MKAnnotation protocol. Then this will be your viewForAnnotation method.

```
   - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[DivvyStation class]]) {

      DivvyStation *divvyStation=(DivvyStation *)annotation

      if (divvyStation.availableBikes.intValue < 1) {
            MKAnnotationView *pin = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
            pin.canShowCallout = YES;
            pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nobikes"];
            return pin; }
      else if (divvyStation.availableDocks.intValue < 1) {
            MKAnnotationView *pin = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
            pin.canShowCallout = YES;
            pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dock"];
            return pin;}
      else {
        MKAnnotationView *pin = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;
        pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Divvy-FB"];
        return pin;
          }
      }
      return nil;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Only change I suggest is to use a plain MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView since the OP wants to use a custom image.  Also minor typo: colon missing after isKindOfClass.

Comment: Thanks - I was on my iPad on a train, so it wasn't the easiest to type :).  I will correct those points.